# "Failed to locate boot function (bootJoomla)" error when installing with cv

Tags: upgrade, joomla, installation, cv

Learning to use cv, and when trying to upgrade CiviCRM with the following command, I get a "Failed to locate boot function (bootJoomla)" error. Any thoughts where I should start digging as to what's wrong?

cv core:install --cms-base-url="[website/CMS_root]" --lang="en_US" --db="mysql://[db_user]:[db_user_pwd]@localhost:3306/[db_name]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not implemented yet:

See https://github.com/civicrm/cv/blob/cf4f644da6d007a32f1c583d68e6b0ae4fe6c45b/src/CmsBootstrap.php#L306

```
// TODO public function bootJoomla($cmsRootPath, $cmsUser) { }
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. Would be nice to mention that in the docu, but perhaps I missed it.

Comment: Are you saying that you just need a CLI funtion to boot joomla for a user who can install?

Comment: It doesn't even need a user for install (but would for the more general use), but it needs appropriate php code to do a joomla bootstrap. For example in wordpress it's just a `require ...` statement (look a little farther down the code). For drupal8 it's a little fancier. If you know what it is for joomla then if you can make a PR great, if not then maybe file an issue at https://github.com/civicrm/cv with some suggested code.